# ng-repeat is not updating when array is pushed inside scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, webmethod

i have a web method which is returning json data in every call  i am pushing this result into a $scope variable , but inside ng-repeat it is not binding this result . whats wrong with my code . please suggest.
here is my code

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetLocationStockEntries(int LocationId, int ProductId)
    {
        var jsonText = (dynamic)null;       
        try
        {

            if (LocationId > 0)
            {
                Int64 BusinessUnitId = 0;
                using (var db = new repute.Data.ReputEntities())
                {
                    var temp = db.Inventories.Where(p => p.InventoryID == LocationId).FirstOrDefault();
                    BusinessUnitId = temp == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(temp.BusinessUnitID);
                    var StockData = db.usp_mvc_InventoryItems_GetAllEntriesByLocation(LocationId, ProductId, BusinessUnitId).Where(x => x.ProjectedQuantityOnHand > 0).ToList();
                    jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { data = StockData });
                }
            }          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return jsonText;
    }
```

js :function which is calling this web method evertime and pushing those result into $scope variable

```
function GetStockEntries(loid, pid)
    {
        return $http.post(serviceURL + "/GetLocationStockEntries", {LocationId: loid, ProductId: pid }).then(
function success(data, status, headers, config) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data.data.d);
    debugger
    //$scope.result = obj.data;
    $scope.result = obj;
    angular.forEach($scope.result, function (key) {
        $scope.StockList.push(key);
    })

},
  function error(data, status, headers, config) {
      return data;
  });
}
```

Html:

```
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" data-ng-repeat="sTockProduct in ProductList" data-ng-cloak>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{sTockProduct.Name}} 
                                <i class="fa fa-expand" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #000000; text-align: right; margin:5px 0px 0px 10px;" data-ng-click="StockListing(sTockProduct);"></i></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" data-ng-repeat="stockItem in StockList track by $index" data-ng-show = "IsVisible" data-ng-cloak width="100%">                                            
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; float: left;">
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="groupName" data-ng-value="true" data-ng-model="stockItem.selected[$index]" data-ng-click="onTaskSelect(stockItem,sTockProduct)" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.UserInventoryItemID" disabled="" readonly="" style="border: none; background-color: white;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.LotNumber" disabled="" readonly="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <!--<input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.QuantityOnHand" disabled="" readonly="">-->
            <span>{{stockItem.QuantityOnHand}}</span>
            <span>{{stockItem.UnitName}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.EnteredQuantity" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="stockItem.Description" disabled="" readonly="">
        </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

Here is the result of json 
[image]

Comment: Is you callback function running? Eg where you put your debugger. Try to console.log the $scope.StockList to inspect the content of it.

Comment: where is this `GetStockEntries` function at and where is it being called?  This *looks* like a service method, but services don't have access to `$scope`.  is this in a controller?

Comment: @ErikSvedin it is returning exactly the no of arrays which is pushed inside $scope.StockList

Comment: is your HTML included file? or is it with your angular code in the same file.

Comment: @Claies yeah that is inside a controller

Comment: I believe you have to add another `ng-repeat` inside your current one, since your array consists of multiple "child" arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the problem is with you ng-repeat.try some thing like, do check a condition there if some thing similar in both item. in your inner table do

> data-ng-if="stockItem.ProductID== sTockProduct.ProductID"

it should be like:

```
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" data-ng-repeat="stockItem in StockList track by $index" data-ng-if="stockItem.ProductID == sTockProduct.ProductID" data-ng-cloak width="100%">
```

and just a slight modification inside your success:

replace :

```
$scope.result = obj;
```

to:

```
$scope.result = obj.data;
```